# Perl Regex-Return the results of the regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with a series of strings. I need the 2 letter state and zip.

```
12354   Jane Jones     123 S Park Ave Kansas City KS 65012


my @token = split $line, \t;
foreach my $token(@token){
> $stateCode = $token =~ /\b(AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MH|MA|MI|FM|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|VI|WA|WV|WI|WY)\s{1,} \d{5,}\b/;}
```

Comment: Explode on tabs, then analyze it?

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Please create one and [edit] your question.

Comment: The answer I was looking for originally has already been done. Modified my question to reflect what I was actually asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need list context to get the matched substring back. You can force list context by enclosing the argument to `my` into parentheses:

```
if (my ($stateCode) = $token =~ /\b(AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MH|MA|MI|FM|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|VI|WA|WV|WI|WY)\s{1,} \d{5,}\b/) {
    print $stateCode, "\n";
```

Comment: No need to shorten the regex as you did. 5.10+ uses a trie for alternations, so you shouldn't get any performance benefits from the groupings.

Comment: Also, the original regex was more readable.  And when the US annexes Canada, the original will be easier to add the extra state(s)! :D  (kidding about the politics, but not about the maintainability)

Comment: OK, OK, removed the shorter part.